# Querying $resource and GridFS

Tags: javascript, gridfs

I'm having troubles getting the response of a query on the client side. The server side works fine, apparently.

This is how the server side query looks like:

```
gfs.files.find({
    "metadata.owner": req.params.driver
}).toArray(function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(err);
    }
    console.log(files); /* files contents the correct result */
    return files;
});
```

And here is my client side, where I don't get a result:

```
GridFS.query({
    driver: user._id
}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res); /* nothing here*/
});
```

Actually, I don't get any error until I refresh the page, when I get this:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/gridfs/5978d197b24dfa0f87160617","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OTc4ZDE5N2IyNGRmYTBmODcxNjA2MTciLCJyb2xlIjoiZHJpdmVyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTAxNDEyMzI1LCJleHAiOjE1MDE0MzAzMjV9.EWCQ6jm_uXe1KQIhMaqnIff8UUeMZfUV8CZfeDI95qk"}},"statusText":""}  vendor.bundle.js:14487:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to send the response:

```
return res.send(files);
```